# Tutorial to install subversion on windows that uses a nas drive as file repository

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server, svn-server

We all have Windows machines but store all our files on a NAS drive, so we don't really have a server, but want to use some kind of version control.

Can anyone recommend a version control software to use and a simple tutorial on how to install and use it, or if not suggest a book to buy that will talk me through it step by step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) and store repositories on a network share (NAS).

Follow the steps provided at [Storing repositories on a network share](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00022/) to setup VisualSVN Server to store it's repositories on a share.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, however, would we all install VisualSvn Server on our machines?

Comment: Install VisualSVN Server on a server machine or on a machine of one of the developers. You will be able to access it via the http(s) and VisualSVN Server will work with the repos stored on a network share.

Comment: Andrew, were you able to get this working? It's not clear to me if VisualSVN Server can store Repositories on a NAS share.

Answer (score -1):

Kind of off topic for stackoverflow, but I will bite.

I would recommend using bitbucket (http://bitbucket.org) with mercurial and tortisehg (http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)  It is not SVN, but centralized SCM going the way of the dinosaur anyway.

Bitbucket is free for up to 5 concurrent users, and allows for unlimited free private repositories.

getting started guide:

http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/quick.html

We are using bitbucket / tortisehg for our large ASP.net project, and loving it so far.  It has tight integration with our bug tracking system (jira)